# 400 Error despite working in Postman, possible reasons?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using the Deepl API, and when I run the request in Postman it is successful, however using it in my app it returns only a 400 Error, which I assume means the headers aren't set up correctly, but it is just how it is in my Postman. Can anyone point out what may be the issue here?

```
async translateMessage(data = {}) {
  const url = "https://api.deepl.com/v2/translate?auth_key=myAuthKey";
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Accept': '*/*'
    },
    body: {
      text: JSON.stringify(this.text),
      target_lang: 'DE',
      source_lang: 'EN'
    }
  });
  return response.json();
},
```

[Example HTTP Post Request from Documentation:](https://www.deepl.com/docs-api/translating-text/request/)

```
POST /v2/translate?auth_key=[yourAuthKey]> HTTP/1.0
Host: api.deepl.com
User-Agent: YourApp
Accept: */*
Content-Length: [length]
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

auth_key=[yourAuthKey]&text=Hello, world&source_lang=EN&target_lang=DE
```

Comment: Is `this.text` just a string?  Have you tried not converting it to JSON first?

Comment: As @BradyHolt mentioned, if you examine the wire from your AJAX call, one difference is that it's sending extra quotes because of the `JSON.stringify`. It's probably something like `auth_key=[yourAuthKey]&text="Hello, world"&source_lang=EN&target_lang=DE`. Why don't you compare the actual headers sent instead of the AJAX call?

Comment: @BradyHolt if I simply use - text: this.text, - it provides me with the same error.

Comment: @JuanMendes Sorry I don't know what the 'wire' refers to. Removing JSON.stringify hasn't worked either. It's also not sending anything in the network dev tools tab.

Comment: [Dev tools' network tab shows you the request](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/#search) that went out, or you could use something like https://www.wireshark.org/ if you really need the raw request.

Comment: @JuanMendes Shouldn't the network tab at least show a failed request? I get the 400 error in Console, but nothing in the Dev tools network tab.

Comment: You must open dev tools tab before the request is issued but if an error occurs it does get logged to the console whether dev tools is open or not.

Answer (score 0):

The `body` property of a URL-encoded message (with the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type) must be either a string of the query parameters, or a [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) instance.

#### Solution

1. Pass the object of key/value pairs to the `URLSearchParams` constructor.
2. You might as well add `auth_key` (one of the required query parameters) to that, and remove it from the URL.
3. Remove `JSON.stringify()` from the `text` property as that would insert unnecessary quotes into the translation.

```js
const url = 'https://api.deepl.com/v2/translate';
const response = await fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Accept': '*/*'
  },            1️⃣
  body: new URLSearchParams({
    auth_key: myAuthKey, 2️⃣
    text: this.text, 3️⃣
    target_lang: 'DE',
    source_lang: 'EN'
  })
});
```